# logstash attempting to connect to elasticsearch instead of loki as output

Tags: logstash, grafana-loki

my logstash is running on kubernetes, logstash attempting to connect to elasticsearch instead of loki as output even if i used

> XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED: false in the env.

```
logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    log.level: debug
    xpack.monitoring.enabled: false
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
     input {
        file{
          path => "/var/log/containers/*.log"
        }
      }
      filter {
         kubernetes {
          source => "path"
          target => "loki"
        }
      }

     output {
      stdout { codec => rubydebug}
      loki {
          url => "http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki-benchmark.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
        }
     }
```

> console output

```
[2022-12-13T06:31:40,411][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-12-13T06:31:50,775][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
[2022-12-13T06:32:10,414][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-12-13T06:32:20,910][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
[2022-12-13T06:32:40,412][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-12-13T06:32:50,998][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
[2022-12-13T06:33:10,410][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
[2022-12-13T06:33:21,328][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
```

> kubernetes config

```
 image: "grafana/logstash-output-loki:1.0.1"
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command:
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-c'
            - 'logstash-plugin install --no-verify logstash-filter-kubernetes && logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf'
```